# Is there any way in CSS to have a child element target a parent element more than one element back?

Tags: html, css, menu

I know there probably is, but here's the situation:

I have a mega menu with links in the tab. I'd like for the tab to show on focus when a link on the inside of the tab has the focus.

Most mega menus only work on hover. I've got the `<li>` to work on focus (because it's right before the  that shows), using `li:focus`. But once you tab to the inside right after the `<li>` and the link inside of that, the `<div>` disappears.

I'm sure there's a way it can be done through jQuery, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't a parent selector. Are you already using `li:hover`? Also, your question is too vague without some HTML/CSS; what's a "mega menu"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use css to select parent element, the only way is to use jQuery parent() method.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS. This will probably be available in CSS4.